# How to embed a shell inside as a component in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

How do you add a CLI as a WPF component. Something similar to what Visual Studio Code does with their terminal.

I have used Hwnd class but that only opened separate windows and did not embed them. I have also tried to use Runspaces.